# Jquery load() open links in same div

Tags: jquery, html, replace, load, hyperlink

I'm so confused I don't even know how to search for an answer to this (I have tried google and here). I'll do my best to word this question as clearly as possible! Basically I have setup a user messaging inbox which is loaded into the user page with load(). I've based it on this method here: http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/using-jquery-load-content-page-without-iframe-536.html

I want it so that all inbox functionality takes place in one div without page reloads. So for example, list all messages, view message, order messages by, delete message etc can be done without page reloads.

So far I have a nice list of inbox messages loaded from inbox.php into a div on member.php. Looks very nice. However, when I click on a link in the "included" inbox list to display a message, it will take me to a new page in the browser. I want the message to load in the same div, replacing the inbox list. The message uri is something like 'inbox/message/321 where 321 is the message ID. How would I do this?

Comment: Place an 'onClick' in the link, have it return 'false' and do a JQuery AJAX call to fetch the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#inbox-div").on("click", "a", function (e) {
    $("#inbox-div").load($(this).attr("href"));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

You could try something like the above.

Basically, it captures when the user clicks on a link inside `#inbox-div`, and uses the jQuery `load` function to load that URL within it.

`e.preventDefault();` is used to stop the browser from redirecting the user to the URL.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that seems to work fine. Just one problem now. The message list contains links to the sender's profile, and I do want those to open in a new page and not within the div :)  How can I override your method on these links?

Comment: You can filter the links, for example: `$("#inbox-div").on("click", "a:not(.profile)", func` ... will not affect the links with class `profile`

Comment: If you mean you want them to open in a new tab, you could filter out elements with _blank targets.  `$("#inbox-div").on("click", "a:not([target=_blank)"`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot. I can go and have a beer now!

Comment: Ok now how would I get that to work with a form submit button?

Comment: that's a little more complicated, i suggest you make a new question. be sure to explain your whole setup again and to include the code you are using

Comment: Thanks, have done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211336/jquery-load-relaoding-content-in-div-via-form-submit-in-div