# jquery .post() is sent as .get()

Tags: jquery, jquery-post

I'll be short I have this function

```js
$("#JqPostForm").submit(function(e){    
    e.preventDefault();  
    $("#despliegaresultados").empty();
    $("#paginacion").empty();
    $.post("php/prueba.php", $('#JqPostForm').serialize(),

    function(data)
    {
        $.each(data, function(i, item)
        {
            total= item.total;
            datos = item.datos;
        });

        //is doing something here 

    });
}, "json");
```

with this html

```html
<html>
.....
   <form>
       <input type="text" name="nombre">
       <input type="submit"> 
   </form>
......
</html>
```

and well it works fine, send and receive post data with json format, my problem is that when i try to save the form in a different html and then retrieve it through a button or something, my call is done with "GET" params and i have no idea why.

I have read the `.load()` from jquery doc, also many post from this site but i don't seem to find any information, i also want to mention that i know .load is by default get, i send some parameters to make it post, this is how i get the form from an external archive

```
$('#target').load('php/searchForm.html',{algo:'algo'});
```

then my form is loaded now on my html, but when i submit it my call changes to "GET". pd. excuse my english i'm not american neither english thanks.

Comment: Syntax error, $.post closed twice? Indent your code properly.

Comment: sorry it's closed twice because i deleted some code for making my post shorter but in my real file is not closed twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after so much looking for i came with this solution 
[jQuery load relaoding content in div via form submit in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211336/jquery-load-relaoding-content-in-div-via-form-submit-in-div)

finally the solution, my problem was solved this way, i moved both files, "index" and "externalForm" to the same directory, both of them on header had
      
and voila i could load an external form and then use it

Answer (score 0):

GET is the default way to send a form, and your form is probably submitted the regular way and not with javascript as there are syntax errors, and if the form is inserted dynamically you'll need delegated event handlers:

```
$('#target').on('submit', '#JqPostForm', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#despliegaresultados, #paginacion").empty();
    $.post("php/prueba.php", $('#JqPostForm').serialize(), function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {

            // NOTE: Ajax is async, the below values are only accessible
            //       after the ajax call has completed

            var total = item.total,
                datos = item.datos;
        });
    }, "json");
});
```

Comment: thanks i have made this and chromes code sniper i get this response Request URL:http://localhost/ambarnew/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK 
i think in the request url is missin prueba.php but i don't know why....

Comment: i think it has to do with Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, all I have is the code you posted, and this should solve any issues with that code as far as I can tell.

Comment: i think i might know where problem is.... i made everything from 0, and i was getting the same mistake i reviewed the code and i was missing id="form", so i checked the complete code and voila... when i load the form, from an external web page, form displays, but code doesn't show! i think there is the problem.... now, do you now why, when i use .load() doesn't display code of loaded page?

Comment: If you use load() the form won't show up in "view source" as it's not in the source, it's added later, and as such regular event handlers won't work, but as you're loading the form into #target, the above should still work. Open the console (F12) and see if there are any errors ?

Comment: well there are not, but going even deeper, i think my problem is even before anything, i made this simple code, <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Title of the document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery10.2.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#load").click()
     {
     $("#result").append("<span>clicked</span>");
     } 
     
     
     });
     
  </script>
 </head>

<body>
<div id="load">
 load form
</div>
<div id="result">
 here we put results
</div>
</body>
</html> and discovered event is triggered even i don't make click

Comment: so i think.... in the other page request method is done even before i load the form..... well thats a very begginer problem but i think thats the answer events are being triggered as dom is ready, pd i have tried to put the event outside dom ready without dom ready and they are beign triggered anyway

Comment: definive there is my trouble look at this simle code, it shows alert as soon as i charge page <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Title of the document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery10.2.js"></script>
  <script>
   $("#load").click()
    {
     alert('clicked');
     
    } 
  </script>
 </head>

<body>
<div id="load">
 load form
</div>
<div id="result">
 here we put results
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: i fixed that with this $(function(){
   

   $("#load").click(function() {
      alert('clicked');
   });
   }); so ill keep constructing everything again thanks for your help

Comment: as soon as i load form, jquery throws this error GET http://localhost/js/jquery10.2.js?_=1374945676191 404 (Not Found) jquery10.2.js:8706
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery10.2.js:612

Comment: i think that's problem, somethings wrong with jquery library+

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to mention

```
<form method="POST">
```

Comment: thakn for your answer i added method post, now it is post but desn´t seem to call page this is what i get
Request URL:http://localhost/ambarnew/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK

Comment: i think it has to do with this... Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded